# Outlook 2013 does not allow reminders to be set in certain folders / PST

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I am using Outlook 2013 (OS Win 7 32-bit), on Microsoft Exchange Server, which has a limited mailbox size. Hence, I have to periodically move the mails to a local PST.

The problem I am facing, when I try to put a follow up reminder on any mail in my local PST, Outlook gives me the following message:

[image]

Any help to get around this would be highly useful. Fiddling with Outlook options did not give me any clue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question at [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-2010-reminders/283229a1-ce32-41ff-9792-e9d06a75afe4)
(But its unclear whether its about mail reminders)

Quoting from the answer:

```
Run the Command given below and check if it helps:

Click on Start< All Programs< Accessories< Run< type ‘Outlook /cleanreminder’ (without quotes)

Note: Ensure there is a space between ‘Outlook’ and ‘/’

Also repair the PST file and check if it helps:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-HA010354964.aspx?CTT=1

If the above steps do not fix the issue create a new profile and check if it works fine:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829918
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. The right clicking on the PST and enabling reminders options worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!
If you installed office 2013 over 2007 or 2010 and are getting this message then the calendar in the left pane will have several different calendars to chose from.  Make sure it is checked for the personal calendar and not an archive calendar. 
Open outlook, select calendar at the bottom and look at the left pane. Check the box for personal Calendar. Uncheck the archive calendar.   Done